# check for point in a polygon

Tags: mysql, sql, polygon, point

This code selects all the rows in the table when the point is hard coded with no errors or warnings:

```
SELECT *
    FROM lat_lng 
    WHERE Contains(
            GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))'),
            GeomFromText('Point(50 50)') )
```

OR defined by variable $var = "50 50" (with no errors or warnings)

```
SELECT *
    FROM lat_lng 
    WHERE Contains(
            GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))'),
            GeomFromText('Point($var)') )
```

However, when I use a column called "location" to define the point, zero rows are selected (with no errors or warnings):

```
SELECT *
    FROM lat_lng 
    WHERE Contains(
            GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))'),
            GeomFromText('Point(location)') )
```

based on this two row sample table:

```
id | location
1  |  50 50
2  |  500 500
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are providing a string which is `Point(location)` (verbatim). What you want is reference the location column, so you'll need to build the string:

```
CONCAT('Point(',location,')')
```

Also you probably want to store the `Point` directly in that other table (rather than text), and then reference it without the `GeomFromText`

**Update**

Storing `Point`s directly in you database:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (id integer primary key auto_increment,location point);
INSERT INTO locations (location) VALUES (Point(50,50));
INSERT INTO locations (location) VALUES (Point(500,500));
```

Request:

```
SELECT id
    FROM locations
    WHERE Contains(
        GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 100,100 100,100 0,0 0))'),
        location);
```

**Update 2**

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5d1f/9